# Putting select count data into a Fetch Array Query row PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, row, fetch

I have a script which retrieves all users with the same "dealership_id" from the "users" table, this works fine. Each user within these records has an ID (users_sales_guild_id) which is also on another table called "sales_list".

What I am trying to do is list the total amount of sales which each user has from the "sales_list" table next to the respective user

Currently it prints the logged in user's amount (John Smith , value of 5), and not each individual amount, where am I going wrong?

**How I would like it to look**

```
Name         |   Position          |    SID    |  Total Sales |  
John Smith   |   Sales Consultant  |    23434  |  5           |   Details
Jane Smith   |   Sales Consultant  |    34234  |  9           |   Details
John Chan    |   Sales Manager     |    43423  |  3           |   Details
Jane Chan    |   Sales Consultant  |    23344  |  7           |   Details
```

**How it looks**

```
Name         |   Position          |    SID    |  Total Sales |  
John Smith   |   Sales Consultant  |    23434  |  5           |   Details
Jane Smith   |   Sales Consultant  |    34234  |  5           |   Details
John Chan    |   Sales Manager     |    43423  |  5           |   Details
Jane Chan    |   Sales Consultant  |    23344  |  5           |   Details
```

**PHP Code**

```
$query = "SELECT `users_id`, `users_email` , `users_sales_guild_id` , `users_dealer_code_id` , 
      `users_first_name` , `users_surname` , `users_dealer_name` , `users_type` ,  DATE_FORMAT(`registration_date`, '%d-%m-%Y') 
      AS `dr` 
      FROM `users` 
      WHERE  `dealership_id` = '".$_SESSION['dealership_id']."'
      AND (users_type = 'Sales Manager' OR users_type = 'Sales Consultant')
      ORDER BY registration_date DESC";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales_list WHERE sales_list.users_sales_guild_id ='" . $_SESSION['users_sales_guild_id'] . "'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

$result = @mysql_query ($query); // Run the query.

echo '<table>
<tr>
<td align="center">Name</td>
<td align="center">Position</td>
<td align="center">ID</td>
<td align="center">Total Sales</td>
<td align="center"></td>
</tr>';

$bg = '#ffffff'; // Set the background color.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

$bg = ($bg=='#e1e3e6' ? '#cdcdcf' : '#e1e3e6'); // Switch the background color.   
echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">';

echo  '<td align="center">' . $row['users_first_name'] . ' ' . $row['users_surname'] . '    </td>';
echo  '<td align="center">' . $row['users_type'] . '</td>';
echo  '<td align="center">' . $row['users_sales_guild_id'] . '</td>';

echo  '<td align="center">' . $num_rows . '</td>';

echo  '<td align="center"><a href="sm-sales-ind-2.php?smid=' . $row['users_id'] . '">Details</td>'; 
}
echo '</table>';

mysql_free_result ($result); // Free up the resources.

mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to add a subquery *or* join to your sql, something similar to:

Join:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(sales_list.*)
FROM salesman
JOIN sales_list ON salesman.id = sales_list.salesman_id
GROUP salesman.id
```

Subquery:

```
SELECT
  name,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales_list 
   WHERE salesmen.id = sales_list.salesman.id) as sales_count
FROM salesmen
```

Then you can use `$row['sales_count']` in the output

The `$num_rows` refers to the number of rows returned, it doesn't contain any specific counts of sales per user

Comment: While this might work, you would have much better results from joining and grouping.

Comment: Updated with a join/group by version

Comment: When I want to count things I generally go with a join/group. But it just popped into my head that with the join/group, there is one small problem. An inner join will exclude rows from salesman where there are no sales rows and if you left join you will return a count of 1 when there are no sales (you will get a sales rows with null values). I generally don't have a problem with doing an inner join and leaving off those results but if OP wants to show them, it might just be better to sub-query.

Comment: I'll try the subquery and join, will let you know how it goes

Comment: Im a little confused, there is no 'salesman' or 'name' table on my database, what am I supposed to use?

Comment: I was just using placeholder names because they aren't important for the answe, I just wanted to convey the idea. Use whatever your tables are... `users` vs salesman, etc

Comment: I've put this query in $sales_count = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales_list WHERE sales_list.users_sales_guild_id = users.users_sales_guild_id) FROM sales_list";
$sales = mysql_result($sales_count); but with no luck

Comment: Show us the schemas of the users/sales_list tables.